# How do I get dynamic libraries to load from the same directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dynamic-library

I have an executable which is dynamically linked to foo.so.0 and bar.so.0. The problem is that when I try to run the executable the loader cannot find the dynamically linked libraries. (The executable was linked to a static library which loaded the dynamic version so I dont control any of that directly). I found that I can edit `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the current directory and then it will find it. The problem is that when the program is run as root, for some reason it still cant find the library. Is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` approach the wrong one? If it is acceptable then why does the program not find the library when run under sudo?

Comment: Why do you want to load libraries from the same directory? Usually the normal mechanism for installing software on Linux is to place binaries  in `/usr/bin` and libraries in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: IIRC sudo clears `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` deliberately. Something like `sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./my-program` should work, as opposed to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. sudo ./my-program`

Comment: @DanielPryden My program is not installed into those directories deliberately.

Comment: `sudo` discards most user-set environment as a security measure.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I will try that in a bit, but is there no better solution? Modifying that environment variable feels like a hack.

Comment: @chacham15 if it's your program, you can use ld's `-rpath` (gcc's `-Wl,-rpath`) to modify library search path for it. (Not that it doesn't feel like a hack too). Or you can install a script starting the program with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Or you can put the libraries where they are searched by default.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko if you wanna go ahead and make that an answer, Ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antons answer: if it's your program, you can use ld's -rpath (gcc's -Wl,-rpath) to modify library search path for it. (Not that it doesn't feel like a hack too). Or you can install a script starting the program with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Or you can put the libraries where they are searched by default.

Answer (score 0):

By default `sudo` [doesn't propagate environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo), especially dangerous ones like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- this is by design because otherwise an unprivileged user could inject libraries into a privileged process by setting environment variables, which would be a pretty huge security hole.

Probably the best solution would be to have a separate launcher stub which can set up the environment for your main program. For instance, you could have a `setuid` program that could launch your main program, or you could have a shell script that users would launch, that would construct the appropriate `sudo` command.

But this feels like a case of *if it hurts, don't do that then*. It sounds like you're intentionally trying to circumvent normal security and administrative measures on a system, which is usually a bad idea. It sounds like you may have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so you might be better served by trying to explain what you're *actually* trying to do, instead of asking about *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: Look at AntonKovalenko's comment. That is the solution I needed.

Comment: @chacham15: Which one? The linker argument, or the wrapper shell script? (The latter is exactly what I proposed in my second paragraph.) Either way, I think my point about an X-Y problem still stands: you've [solved half your problem, and now you want to solve the half that doesn't make sense](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx).

Comment: @chacham15: Also, if you've found the solution you needed, go ahead and add it as an answer (or convince Anton to do so), and mark it as accepted. That way the question is marked as answered.